# Boundary not working with inset faces command

Tags: faces, mirror

I'm working on Blender Guru's anvil tutorial.  At [this point](https://youtu.be/lITV4F_P4E0?t=424) he insets a face and uses the boarder option to achieve the desired result.  I'm using v2.9 which no longer supports the B shortcut, but I can enable it in the new sub-menu for the command.  Nevertheless, nothing happens and the boarder piece remains, so I can't perform the extrude on a single entity; it comes out as two spikes.
What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: It will work only when the boundary is open and not closed by any face.

Answer (score 10):

If you turn off the Mirror, you will see that your anvil has a face inside look at the image, once you delete that you will be able to use inset as expected

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  How do I turn off the mirror?  I know how to delete it, but not turn it off temporarily.

Comment: If you go to the Mirror modifier, you will see some blue icons on the left side of the name "Mirror" click on those to turn it on and off

Comment: Aah, got it.  Thanks.  Unfortunately, it still doesn't solve my problem.  I'd post a screenshot, but I don't know how.  Blend-exchange only lets me upload .blend files.

Comment: Not sure why did not worked for you, i just switched the image for an animated gif, take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

I actually encountered the same issue, and wasn't even working after trying @emir process (on the answer).
The only way I found was to move the inset face until it snapped the central edge.
I haven't finished the anvil yet so i don't know if it will cause me problems, but for the moment it's OK

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: delete the hidden face as suggested above by Emir. but then also delete this edge. the reconnect the two vertices to create the same edge and then try the inset. it worked for me and I hope this helps.  [image: this edge] or just turn on clipping in the mirror modifier ( I just found that one out.
[image: connect these vertices]