# How do i destroy a specific boundary when inseting

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, vertices

I'm following Blender Gurus tutorial where he instructs to click <kbd>B</kbd> during an *Inset* in order to dissolve a border, but when I click <kbd>B</kbd> nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: maybe you've extruded by accident and it made overlapping verices. Try Alt M > Merge By Distance and do the inset again. If it still desn't work, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hello :). You need to remove on of the side faces.

Comment: [inset faces, Blender tutorial](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/197410/boundary-not-working-with-inset-faces-command/197427#197427)

Comment: Thank you, Emir, that really helped,  I did upload the file moonboots, and thank you for that info but there were no overlapping vertices(and btw its M not alt m to merge vertices you may have changed that key but thanks anyways), this is beautiful I've finally found the solution thanks guys.