# Inset surface problems

Tags: modeling, texturing

i used inset surfaces, and then hit B to eliminate the boundary. But when i do the same thing, it doesn't work, so can someone tell me why?[image]

Comment: Hello, it looks like it's missing in 3.6.4, in that case it should be reported. It's back in 4.0 alpha by the way so they must be aware. If you are using a previous version, check the answers here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/197410/boundary-not-working-with-inset-faces-command

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! I got the same result by adding loop cuts. Anyway thank you for solving my problem!

Comment: @moonboots The 'B' Boundary hotkey is working fine here in 3.6.4 and I see that the problem is solved by the link you gave. You didn't have an internal face when you checked it did you? :^))

Comment: Oh yes that's weird I couldn't make it work but now it does

Comment: Cosmic rays strike again! :^)

Comment: i will try it later, thanks teacher John :)